# How do I test if my RapidSSL certificate will work with older mobile browsers?

Tags: ssl, ssl-certificate, https, android

I read this bug report about [RapidSSL certificates not being recognised by older versions of Android](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=15968). I've got the necessary [certificate chain from here](https://knowledge.rapidssl.com/library/VERISIGN/ALL_OTHER/RapidSSL%20Intermediate/RapidSSL_CA_bundle.pem), but I don't have an Android device to test on.

So how can I test if the certificate is set up properly?

Comment: Trivial answer it might be, but if you put the URL into your question, those of us with Android devices could test it, and let you know.  There's no test suite like reality!

Answer (score 0):

The bug report linked to states that:

> Android has always included the root CA
>
> subject= /C=US/O=Equifax/OU=Equifax Secure Certificate Authority

So to ensure that it works across the board, you can check using the older Equifax certificate which has been recognised by browsers for longer. The command (on Ubuntu at least) is:

```
gnutls-cli --x509cafile /etc/ssl/certs/Equifax_Secure_CA.pem -p 443 www.example.org
```